# How I can set nuget package allowedversion only at solution level?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-4.5, nuget-cli, nuget-console

I use VS 2015 and .net 4.5 web project with 15 project.

I use by example a package in a couple of projects of my solution and each time I need to change the version for a specific version I need to open the package.config for each projects add allowedVersions.

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure globally only one time the allowedVersions instead of openning each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can set nuget package allowedversion only at solution level?

I am afraid you could not set `allowedversion` at solution level.

That because the `allowedVersions` attribute is used typically during update operations to constrain the versions in the `packages.config` file, and `packages.config` file is used for project level.

The NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0. So we could not pull this attribute `allowedversion` from the `package.config` file and apply it to the solution level.

Besides, the attribute `allowedversion` can be a range value and does not need to be a specific value. Does your project have strict restrictions on the nuget package version? Can it only be a specific version? If not, you can give a version range to the attribute `allowedversion` not using a specify version, like:

```
allowedVersions="[1.3.2,1.5)"
```

If you can only use a specific version in your project, I am afraid you have to openning each file to change that attribute.